# Implementation for stop words in python

Tags: python

What is more fast for a list of stop words in python:

```
 stopwords = ('a','and', 'etc')
```

or to use a file to call it?

Comment: You should be more specific - what do you intend to do with `stopwords`?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking: which will run faster at runtime: creating a list (or tuple) literal, or reading the list from a file?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

`NLTK` has stopwords as a list.

```
nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
```

It is faster than using a file and reading from it while going over the stopwords, if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

File operations are always much slower than normal code execution. So, if the data you need is small enough, never go for files.

You go with files if any of the following is true:

- Need to modify input data without changing the actual code
- Large amount of data to process
- Data is being fed by another process/application

If you only have a finite number of stop words and if you don't need to change them often, then always go with

```
stopwords = ('a','and', 'etc')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to download `nltk`, stopword files can be found everywhere. They usually list one word per line so its easy to put those in an own structure.

```
stopwords = ()
for line in open('stopwordfile'):
    stopwords += (line,)
```

However, faster than looking up words in a tuple is using a dictionary, probably preferably with a default return value:

```
stopdict = {w:True for w in stopwords}

for word in text_you_want_to_index:
     if word not in stopdict:          # or: not stopdict.get(word, False): don't know which one more performant
          print word
```

Comment: `set` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: I agree. We can even go further and recommend using `frozenset`, since it is unlikely to be neccessary to add or remove elements once set up.